# Reading package list...Done

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

I am facing an issue that when I type that command (`sudo apt-get update`) after adding lines in source list, for updating the source list. It shows (reading package list...Done) So I'm not able to install any application by this command (`apt-get install package-name`). I have tried many other Kali Linux releases. Now I'm trying (Kali.64x.2016.2.amd64).

I also tried (`sudo apt-get disk-upgrade`) Or combine command. But with that command I'm getting this:

```
Reading package list....Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
Calculating upgrade.... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So no changes anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't know why somebody downvoted your question. I have faced the same problem just now and I think I've solved it.

The apt-* commands are actually working but there is a minor quirk here. Probably your /etc/apt/sources.list is empty too, just like my installation.

I have created a bootable flash disk with Rufus but since it uses ISO image as default instead of DD, Kali detected the flash disk as a CD. I unplugged and plugged the flash to solve this problem. Maybe you did like I did because there are commented out sources in sources.list file which includes lines with "[CD-ROM]".

If this is the case, here is your solution. Just paste the line below, to top of your /etc/apt/sources.list file and try apt-* commands again.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Thank you bro. I got the exact same thing. I did the remove and re-add of the usb, and not there's nothing on my sources.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar issue with Kali Linux and this is what I did to fix the issue.

When you type `leafpad /etc/apt/source.list` in your terminal, and your list is empty, then that is not the list you should edit. Select open, and you will see another source.list, click on that one and paste the new list, save it and exit.

Update your repository and there you have it.

Hope it works for you!!!